# Interest rate control variable GARCH

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, garch, macroeconomics, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm building a GARCH model which looks if analysts' reports affect the volatility of certain stocks. I was wondering if it would be logical to include the interest rate in my GARCH model as a sort of control variable for macroeconomic changes.

Maybe a change in volatility doesn't come from the report per se, but underlying changes in monetary policy for instance.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I need to ask: how are you modeling analyst reports in a time series? And how do you expect to estimate the impact of a report using a GARCH model?

Comment: @KevinLi, thanks for responding, and sorry for the late reply. I'm using a topic modeling program, which divided the contents of the reports in 20 topics. I choose a topic of interest, and I see the proportion of that topic per report. As such, I see the distribution of that topic over time. This topic proportion I regress on the conditional variance of the GARCH model.

Answer (score 2):

Research in linking financial market volatility and macroeconomic fundamentals has been a widely studied topic. Different interest rates and related variables have been included in papers from the financial econometrics literature.

The most common approach is to consider a additive GARCH-X model (here GARCH(1,1) for notional convenience). Denote the "exogenous" variables that you want to include by the vector $x_t$. The model can then be written as:
\begin{align}
r_t =&  \mu + \varepsilon_t =\mu +  \sigma_t z_t \\
\sigma_t^2 =& \omega + \beta \sigma_{t-1}^2 +  \alpha \varepsilon_{t-1}^2 + \gamma^\prime x_{t-1}
\end{align}
where $z_t$ is assumed to be $iid(0,1)$. We lag the exogenous variables one period such that they are included in the information set at time $t$.

This approach of adding the exogenous variables additively directly to the GARCH equation has different draw backs. One being that the conditional variance may be negative when e.g. rates becomes negative, which is implausible.

An alternative route would be to consider an multiplicative specification. Then assume that the conditional variance can be written as $\sigma_t^2 = g_t h_t$, where 
\begin{align}
h_t =& \omega + \beta h_{t-1} +  \alpha \left(\varepsilon_{t-1}/\sqrt{g_{t-1}} \right)^2
\end{align}
and 
\begin{equation}
g_t = \gamma^\prime x_{t-1}
\end{equation}
such that the scaled returns follow a "normal" GARCH process while $g_t$ governs the baseline volatility.

To avoid the possibility of a negative variance due to the exogenous variables, one could assume: 
\begin{equation}
g_t = \exp\left({\gamma^\prime x_{t-1}} \right)
\end{equation}

Another important note is that the relationship between macroeconomic fundamentals often is heavily non-linear. Thus, using models with a smooth transition specification may be nice. You also may have a look at the GARCH-MIDAS model that is used extensively for research in linking macroeconomic variables with volatility.

A google search will give you a lot of interesting research articles on this topic!

Comment: @ Johan thank you! A beautiful answer. Would you mind if I ask you a follow-up question when I've studied the GARCH-X and GARCH-MIDAS models further?

Comment: @Pthiel No. Please just reach out - I have worked quite a lot with these specifications. You may find this interesting https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3071822.  Consider up voting the answer, if you find it useful.

Comment: @ Johan GARCH-MIDAS seems almost perfect as to what I'm looking for. However, say that I would like to include the interest rate, and I have data for the daily interest rate (which is the same frequency as my other variables). Would this give me similar results?

Comment: @pthiel you are free to use data at the samme frequency. Note that it often is best to start with a simple model say gatch x and then add complexity if misspecification tests call for it.

Comment: @ Johan, I've checked up some more on the literature, and I've decided on a GARCH-MIDAS model. As for the macroeconomic 'control variables', I've opted for interest rates and economic cycles (using a variable proxy from CLI from OECD). Would you say that those two would cover the macroeconomic aspect well enough? Or should I add additional ones such as inflation for example? This is more so a theoretical question than strictly technical.

Comment: @Pthiel One possibility would be to consider the ADS index that is a real time proxy for macroconditions. It is very hard to answer whether you have included enough macro variables - it is more an empirical question. Does adding additional variables increase the fit of the model.

Comment: @ Johan, thank you for your answers, I think I figured it out (hopefully).

Comment: @Pthiel Perfect!