# Macroeconomic variables in GARCH

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, garch, macroeconomics

I'm using a **GARCH model which studies the relationship between news effects and the commodity market**. In the model, I would also like to **include some macroeconomic variables**, e.g. interest rates or inflation, as these would likely also influence volatility.

I've been suggested a GARCH-MIDAS, but estimation with additional regressors only seems feasible in R, which I'm not familiar with. Are there any other ways of including these variables? For example, would it be possible to include a variable for (daily) interest rates in the conditional variance in an EGARCH?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to add exogenous variables directly to the "GARCH" equation in both GARCH, GJR-GARCH, EGARCH, and other volatility models. However, the asymptotic theory is not established yet in the case of the EGARCH model.

If you use Matlab, I believe that there is an implementation of the GARCH-MIDAS model.

You may have a look at the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359168/interest-rate-control-variable-garch#359211)